# Azure functions static isolation

Tags: c#, azure, static, azure-functions

I haven't been able to find much documentation on the isolation of Azure functions in an app service plan.

If you share a static variable for example an `HttpClient` between azure function invocations I presume reading through the scalability suggestions that it *could* run in the same process or separate processes or separate servers... which is fine, using `Lazy<T>` can help with threading issues.

But could separate Azure Functions share a worker process? i.e. should I isolate static variables to ensure isolation of the functions? I gather using a `ConcurrentDictionary` with a key for the function is a good approach to help solve this, but I haven't found any documentation that discusses isolation.

Comment: The only thing we can do to stop retagging suggestions is to lock the entire question, which will also prevent anyone from voting on it, commenting, etc. That would not be appropriate here. Frankly, I don't understand why you object to the [[tag:azure]] tag. How can a tag be "too broad"? [[tag:azure-functions]] is a subset of [[tag:azure]], so the latter also seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray for looking into it. I suppose I'd considered it too broad because azure-functions encompasses azure. It isn't an azure problem, but very specifically to do with azure-functions. It's similar to a c# question being tagged with .net (well kind of, but that's the best analogy I can think of at the moment :-) ) I'll bow down to the community, if it gets tagged again I'll approve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can manage this by having one or many Function Apps:

- Different functions of the same Function App will be running in the same process and will reuse any static state with other functions of the same app running on the same host.
- Functions of different Function Apps are isolated from each other.

To see that visually you may go to Kudu (of each app). On Environment tab you see a machine name, so you may check that two apps are running on the same machine. Then, on Process Explorer tab you will see a `w3wp.exe` process assigned to a specific Function App.