# Two Azure Functions share an In-Proc collection

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-async

I have two Azure Functions. I can think of them as "Producer-Consumer". One is "HttpTrigger" based Function (Producer) which can be fired randomly. It writes the input data in a static "ConcurrentDictionary". The second one is "Timer Trigger" Azure Function(consumer). It reads the data periodically from the same  "ConcurrentDictionary" which was being used by the "Producer" function App and then do some processing.

Both the functions are within the same .Net project (but in different classes). The in-memory data sharing through static "ConcurrentDictionary" works perfectly fine when I run the application locally. While running locally, I assume that they are running under the same process. However, when I deploy these Functions in Azure Portal ( They are in the same function App Resource), I found that data sharing through  static "ConcurrentDictionary"  is not not working.

I am just curious to know, if in Azure Portal, both the Functions have their own process (Probably, that's why they are not able to share in-process static collection). If that is the case, what are my options that these two Functions work as proper "Producer-Consumer"? Will keeping both the Functions in the same class help?

Probably, the scenario is just opposite to what is described in the post - "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203987/do-azure-function-from-same-app-service-run-in-same-instance". As against the question in the post, I would like both the Functions to use the same static member of a static class instance.

I am sorry that I cannot experiment too much because the deployment is done through Azure-DevOps pipeline. Too many check-ins in repository is slightly inconvenient. As I mention, it works well locally. So, I don't know how to recreate what's happening in Azure Portal in local environment so that I can try different options? Is there any configurable thing which I am missing to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, use an azure queue, event grid, service bus or something else that is reliable but just don't try using a shared object. It will fail as soon as scale out happens or as soon as one of the processes dies. Do think about functions as independent pieces and do not try to go against the framework.

Yes, it might work when you run the functions locally but then you are running on a single machine and the runtime might use the same process but once deployed that ain't true anymore.

If you really really don't want to decouple your logic into a fully seperated producer and consumer then write a single function that uses an in process queue or collection and have that function deal with the processing.